# How do I correctly place a header image in a Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using this premium Wordpress theme for a client and originally I had to sort of hack the PHP a bit to get the logo centered. By default, you put the logo in the theme's "logo" dialogue and it places it in the traditional top-left position.

Anyway, the client rebranded and it now makes sense for the logo to go back to the top-left. However, now I get multiple logos and can't figure out why for the life of me! I still want the green "Growing Underground" stamp image in the position it is in now.

http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/

Any ideas? I fear I have made a terrible mess.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Oops! Here's the bit I had added to header.php

<!--HEADER -->
  <div id="header">
   
 
 <div id="logo-container"><a http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk"><img src="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ZCF-new-logo.png" alt="" /></a><a href="http://www.growing-underground.com" class="stamp"><img src="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/GU-stamp.png"></a></div>

Comment: Why don't you just go back to the original version of the header?

Comment: Your logo is tucked in a link that is sorted out right. If you change styling within in the IMG, it does you no good. Change the a, in which it is tucked, to left and you have it on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#logo-container a{background:url('http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1395756694ZCF-new-logo.png') no-repeat;}
```

This is creating the issue.

Remove `background:url('http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1395756694ZCF-new-logo.png') no-repeat;` from this class.

Comment: I can't find this in style.css. Could it be one of the many php files perhaps?

Comment: This is not in your `style.css` file. Check your `header.php` file.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is fixed now. I messed around with some bits of header.php, style.css and nothing was happening. There seems to be other bits of the stylesheet that are accessed via "additional styles" in the back-end of the theme. That seems to be where I was going wrong. Anyway I think it is sorted now and appreciate your help (and patience).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the following:

```
#logo-container a {
    background: url('http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1395756694ZCF-new-logo.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Secondly, change:

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

to

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And thirdly, change:

```
#logo-container img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to

```
#logo-container img {
    display: block;
}
```